# using Python2.7 requests ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, connection-refused

I'm working on a small project and I'm try to send json data from a sensor node to a server using the url they gave me. It was working for a couple of days until today, it keeps saying ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')). I have a couple of nodes on the same network and all of them cannot send. I tried sending data to the server using a node on a different network and ISP and it's a success.

I'm using pythonv2.7 and requests lib version: 2.4.3

here is the code:

```
import time
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://czwxxx.org/pxxx_API/v1/node1'
MAC = "v0 v0 v0 v0 v0 v0"
time = int(round(time.time()*1000))
data = {"MAC":MAC,"time":time,"x_raw":'0',"y_raw":'0',"z_raw":'0','status':'1'}
requests.post(url,data=data)
```

Here is the traceback

```
    sudo python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    requests.post(url,data=data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))
```

I tried setting iptables to accept all traffic and to no avail. below is the output

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Checking on netstat -pn|grep :80 it seems getting stuck at SYN_SENT and not receiving a reply?

```
sudo netstat -pn|grep :80
tcp        0      1 192.168.8.104:34856     166.62.28.86:80         SYN_SENT    13751/python
```

I'm not sure if the problem is in my internet, node configuration, or firewall. I'm kind of new to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in Jenkins and is definitely related to python on the server. Please make sure you have the compatible version of python and the only version of python installed on the server where you are running this. Hopefully this helps.